# djanago channels CRITICAL Listen failure: Couldn't listen on 0.0.0.0:x: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels, daphne, django-supervisor

I am trying to deploy my ASGI application.
I have followed the exact docs of https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html

But when I am checking my logs i am ending up with:
`CRITICAL Listen failure: Couldn't listen on 0.0.0.0:x: [Errno 98] Address already in use.`

I have tried changing ports but at last, ending up with the same:

Eg: for port **8005** `daphne -p 8005 -b 0.0.0.0 myproject.asgi:application`
I am ending up with:

```
Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne1.sock
2020-07-16 08:22:10,324 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, tcp:port=8005:interface=0.0.0.0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2020-07-16 08:22:10,324 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2020-07-16 08:22:10,325 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2020-07-16 08:22:10,345 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8005
2020-07-16 08:22:10,345 INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8005:interface=0.0.0.0
```

In my **asgi.log** file.

My `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/abc.conf` file:

```
[fcgi-program:isbuddy]
# TCP socket used by Nginx backend upstream
socket=tcp://localhost:8005

# Directory where your site's project files are located
directory=/home/bhaskar/myprojectdir

# Each process needs to have a separate socket file, so we use process_num
# Make sure to update "mysite.asgi" to match your project name
command=/home/bhaskar/venv/bin/daphne -p 8005  -b 0.0.0.0 -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers myproject.asgi:application

# Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
numprocs=2

# Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

# Automatically start and recover processes
autostart=true
autorestart=true

# Choose where you want your log to go
stdout_logfile=/home/bhaskar/asgi.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

My `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abcd` as:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}
location @proxy_to_app {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8005;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

}

I tried all the possibilities available by checking every docs.
I want my website to run in my public IP.

Comment: whatever your original port you used, it was apparently used by some other service on your system.  That said,  now that you've got it working,  what is the issue?

Comment: When I do `daphne -p 8005 myproject.asgi:application` in my project directory it is working good but when I trying to deploy I am ending up like this.